# Tag synonym request [date] -> [date-time]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The date-time (or DateTime) object represents a specific instance of an object, where date often is a format of a DateTime instance.

Thus I want to suggest a synonym of tag [date](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) to the master tag [date-time](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-time).

[date](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) -> [date-time](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-time)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think it makes sense to keep both so I've merged date to [date-time](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-time).

Comment: You can merge too? Nice!